# How to create random seed

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing

Suppose I fork an R process into 10 workers to run some parallel simulations. What would be a reliable method to make sure that each worker uses different random numbers? I been using this:

```
myseed <- (unclass(Sys.time())*1e9 * Sys.getpid()) %% 1e9;
set.seed(myseed);
```

However to my surprise I was getting problems due to RNG clashes between workers. What could have gone wrong here? Is there a better source of randomness that I can use to seed the RNG?

Comment: Try the `doRNG` package, which is built expressly for this purpose.

Comment: There is also the old granddaddy of parallel RNGs in package rsprng (which is also in Debian / Ubuntu) relying on the SPRNG library (which also is packaged).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `vignette("parallel")` section 6 for details of how this can be done using functions from that package, which seem independent of using **parallel**'s functions for parallel runs.

The example given there is:

```
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(<something>)
## start M workers
s <- .Random.seed
for (i in 1:M) {
  s <- nextRNGStream(s)
  # send s to worker i as .Random.seed
}
```

That vignette also mentions the **[rstream](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rstream)** and **[rlecuyer](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rlecuyer)** packages, in addition to the **[doRNG](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doRNG)** package, that @Simon O'Hanlon mentions in his comment, and the **[rsprng](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rsprng)** package mentioned by @Dirk.

Comment: And the parallel package also has the `clusterSetRNGStream` function which does the above in 1 step.  The only time I can see that this solution would not be sufficient is if each process needed to generate a multiple of 2^127 random numbers, but this seems like it would not occur very often.

Comment: @GregSnow Thanks, isn't that just for SNOW clusters (though same behaviour is in `mcapply` and `mcparallel`)? Bit rusty on **parallel** as haven't used it much, yet...

Comment: Looking at the code for the function, it is basically what you included above from the vignette (with some extra checking, finding M automatically, etc.), so it should work on any cluster that that `sendCall` would work on.  The parallel package works on more than just snow clusters.